# How to get linked components used on a page using core service

Tags: core-service

If I have a page called BluePage and it uses a component called BlueComponent, using core service, how would I find linked components that show up on the page but are not directly used by the page. For example, a PDF multimedia component linked in the BlueComponent. When the page renders, the PDF shows up. I need to write a report that will list any object used on a page whether it directly used by the page or as a linked component. Does anyone have any code samples they can share?

Answer (score 7):

I think this code can help. This will give you the first level of Linked Components for existing component presentations in a page

```
IEnumerable<XElement> links = null;
XNamespace xLinkNS = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");

CoreServiceClient channel = new CoreServiceClient();

PageData page = (PageData)channel.Read("[PageId]", new ReadOptions());
foreach (ComponentPresentationData cp in page.ComponentPresentations) {
    ComponentData component = (ComponentData)channel.Read(cp.Component.IdRef, new ReadOptions());

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(component.Content)) {
        XElement xContent = XElement.Parse(component.Content);
        XNamespace xNS = XNamespace.Get(xContent.FirstAttribute.Value);

        links = xContent.Descendants().Where(w => w.Attributes(xLinkNS + "href").Count() > 0);
    }

    foreach (XElement link in links) {
        // Linked Components
    }
}
```